# Google cardboard for unity build errors

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

### The problem

I'm trying to build google cardboard for unity on my android and getting build errors

- I have unity 2020.3.37f1 with android build support
- I followed the quickstart - https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart
- I have the `HelloCardboard` scence in my `Scences in build`
- I have my phone plugged in
- I'm getting a gradle error

### The error

[image]

also I don't know if it's related but when I try to play the `HelloCardboard` scence, it keeps throwing this error:
[image]

### What i've tried

- changing the player settings (API, target arch...)
- emulated several phones in android studio
- downloaded JDK and android SDK tools instead of the *recommended*

Answer (score 0):

The error says you should initialize the XR Loader.

There is a checkbox for "Initialize XR on Startup" in Project Settings, under XR Plug-in Management section. And you have to select the Plug-in Provider, which in this case should be "Cardboard XR Plugin".

You may also initialize the Loader at runtime in the code if you instead want the app to start in 3d. It's all in the documentation.